# Gnome in Ubuntu Server

Tags: gnome, server, gui

I have installed GUI in Ubuntu server using

```
sudo apt-get ubuntu-desktop --no installrecommends
```

I have started it using

```
startx
```

I have accessed the home folder using(since there is no icons)

```
nautilus
```

Is there any other way to open the home folder?
If I restart my server will it automatically go to the GUI or the to the login prompt at the command line?

Comment: Why did you use "--no installrecommends" ? You almost certainly need additional packages. Also why gnome-desktop ? If you need a graphical interface to manage your server you are far better off with a web based tool such as webmin.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and edit your system wide crontab.

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

After last hash-tag enter and save the following line.

```
@reboot root lightdm
```

After several reboots, system seems to have no problems. And hopefully never will. Can't say for sure that this is the best solution...

Comment: What makes you think rebooting a number of times will fix anything ?